# Type per user in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm designing an analytics platform. Every user has access only to his own documents. All the documents have the same structure.

The default option is to have a userId field and use it every time I need to filter documents.

The question is **will type per user improve search performance?**

Comment: I think it's pretty much the same as adding a `term` filter for `userId` in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

No, type per user won't improve your performance. It is exactly the same as filtering by the field. 
But, you may consider using "filtered aliases". Since you actualy want to make different "views" for the same index you may create different aliases filtered by the userId as stated [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html).